# Trying to upgrade tensorflow code for newer version

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a neural network to write texts, based on a list of texts from a corpus.

Specifically the code I am trying to recreate in an old tensorflow version for tensorflow 2.0 is what I need help with:

```
INTERNALSIZE = 512
NLAYERS = 3learning_rate = 0.001  # fixed learning rate
dropout_pkeep = 0.8    # some dropout
```

However the old code was:

`from tensorflow.contrib import rnn`

and the code I am trying to update is:

```
cells = [rnn.GRUCell(INTERNALSIZE) for _ in range(NLAYERS)]
```

I have run

```
!tf_upgrade_v2 \
```

on it but it has not updated this line. How can I generate these cells in large numbers as opposed to having to use individual layers?

Comment: GRUCell is still there in `from tf.compat.v1.nn import rnn_cell`. Here is the doc, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/rnn_cell/GRUCell

Comment: thankyou. Do you know if layers.linear exists in 2.0 as well?

Comment: layers.linear present in Tensorflow Lattice as `tfl.layers.Linear`.

For more information on the library please check here https://www.tensorflow.org/lattice/api_docs/python/tfl/layers/Linear